# Magento 2 USPS API estimated delivery date (standards and commitments api)

Tags: magento2, shipping, usps

How can I add estimate delivery date for **USPS** shipping method? I am searching over google but no luck, how can I achieve this in **Magento 2**.

I did this in **UPS** and want the same in **USPS**.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more details? It's not clear to me. We can use the default or we want to add more shipping carriers to USPS?

Comment: We use default USPS shipping carriers we just display estimate time to deliver behind shipping label please check my edited question i do it in UPS and need to want same in USPS

Comment: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm-api.htm   hope it help you

Comment: Actually  USPS don't provide estimation delivery date in  API